# How to dump the request and response headers between squid and upstream proxy?

Tags: logging, openwrt, squid

I have squid web proxy setup on OpenWRT router. The proxy is configured to use upstream corporate proxy. I am wondering if there is a way to dump request/response headers for every outgoing request to cache peer.